# knockout.js observable only updates on array push

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm in the mist of learning knockout and am stuck on some functionality

I have an observable to calculate totals from values in an Observable array. Unfortunately it is only updating on push or remove, but I want it to also update on replace and when I update an attribute of one of the objects in the array, is there some way to manually trigger the update?

```
        self.basketTotal = ko.observable();
        self.basketItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.getTotals = ko.computed(function(){
             var total = 0;
             ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.basketItems(), function(item) {
                 total += parseFloat(ko.utils.unwrapObservable( parseInt( item.productPrice() )) );
             });
            self.basketTotal(total);
        });
```

Comment: why you need a additional observable to store total ? directly return the total & bind the `getTotals` to view . coming to your updating part it should go smooth . sample with your issue would be helpful . FYI `item.productPrice()` does the unwrapping no need of `unwrapObservable` keep it simple like this ` total += parseFloat(item.productPrice());` cheers

Comment: Thanks you were right productPrice was holding onto the unit price not the calculated price and thanks for the unwrapObservable pointer, makes things a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@super cool 's comment on the inital post was the right answer

"why you need a additional observable to store total ? directly return the total & bind the getTotals to view . coming to your updating part it should go smooth . sample with your issue would be helpful . FYI item.productPrice() does the unwrapping no need of unwrapObservable keep it simple like this ` total += parseFloat(item.productPrice());"

```
             var total = 0;
             ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.basketItems(), function(item) {
                 total += parseFloat( parseInt( item.productQtyPrice() ) );
             });

            self.basketTotal(total);
```

To answer the question about the additional observable, I'm using it to calculate all sorts of things like discounts and tax etc so theres a few steps in between excluded from the sample code to make the problem at hand a bit clearer, the issue at hand was simply the wrong calculation was being done (technically it was working code) and super cools comment helped to point that out.